# Harbor Breeze Ceiling fan lights flash after being on for about 10 minutes or so

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan

We have a Harbor Breeze ceiling fan that has been working perfectly for about 2-3 years. Now, whenever we turn the lights on they start to blink after approximately 10 minutes or so. We changed the bulbs to LED bulbs about a year ago, but it just started the "blinking" a couple months ago. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing *one* of the lamps back to incandescent. Some lamp controllers require a steady drain, and as the LED's or controller aged, it may have gotten more finicky. A low-wattage lamp should be fine, though it does reduce efficiency slightly.